# Overlaying points over gadm map

Tags: r

I [have already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278264/plot-points-map-of-population) about plotting points dependent on region, but now my question is about overlaying points given by coordinations over gadm map. I want to show different meteostations, using data based on this [site](http://www.tageo.com/index-e-rs-weather-rs-step-4.htm) or here is  [data used in code](http://files.mail.ru/FB13505A8F164ABF8BB18671DA89CC8F) I've tried using such code:

```
require(ggplot2)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(gpclib)
library(rgeos)
library(PBSmapping)
gpclibPermit()
rus<-load("C://RUS_adm1.RData")
proj4.str <- CRS("+init=epsg:3413 +lon_0=105")
gadm.prj <- spTransform(gadm, proj4.str)
rus<-gadm.prj

met <- read.csv2('C:\\meteo.txt')


cds <- data.frame(
                  Longitude=met$Long,
                  Latitude=met$Lat)

k<-as.matrix(cds)



popSP <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=k,met["Elevation"], proj4string=proj4.str)

spplot(popSP, sp.layout=list('sp.polygons', gadm.prj))
```

Following advice from already mentioneed question, but it ends up with plotting points w/o gadm layer [image].

I guess it's because of non-mentioning regions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having checked your input location file, the whole thing became very clear which shows that you should always check ASCII data before working with it.

`meteo.txt` contains Lon/Lat coordinates multiplied by 1000. Hence, the only this you have to do is divide the respective columns by 1000 and assign an appropriate Lon/Lat projection to your data. If you wish, you could reproject the whole stuff to EPSG:3413 afterwards. In fact, this looks prettier when plotting your data.

Here's the code.

```
# Required packages
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

# Administrative data (taken from http://www.gadm.org/)
rus <- load("/path/to/RUS_adm1.RData")

# Point data (taken from http://files.mail.ru/FB13505A8F164ABF8BB18671DA89CC8F)
popSP <- met <- read.csv2("/path/to/meteo.txt")
for (i in c(3, 4)) 
  popSP[, i] <- popSP[, i] / 1000

coordinates(popSP) <- ~ Long + Lat
projection(popSP) <- projection(gadm)

# Reprojection to EPSG:3413 (see http://www.spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/3413/)
proj4.str <- CRS("+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=105 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")

gadm.prj <- spTransform(gadm, proj4.str)
popSP.prj <- spTransform(popSP, proj4.str)

# Plotting
png("/path/to/russia_points.png", width = 800, height = 500)
plot(gadm.prj)
points(popSP.prj, pch = 16, cex = .5, col = "red")
dev.off()
```

[image: russia_points.png]

---

Here's a swift implementation of how to plot data from the shapefile using `spplot` with locations superimposed. See for example [this tutorial](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/book/export/html/962) if you'd like to find out more about handling `spplot`.

```
spplot(gadm.prj, "PID", 
       sp.layout = list("sp.points", popSP.prj, cex = .5, pch = 16, col = "red"))
```

[image: russia_points_spplot]